# nameref (hyperref) evaluating counter instead of section name

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

What's the proper way to reference a section with a counter in the title? The TOC generates correctly, but the cross references aren't so lucky.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, twoside]{exam}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{KSRLessonNumberCounter}
\setcounter{KSRLessonNumberCounter}{1}
\newcommand{\KSRSection}[2][\value{KSRLessonNumberCounter}]{
        \setcounter{KSRLessonNumberCounter}{#1}
        \section*{Lesson \arabic{KSRLessonNumberCounter}: #2}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Lesson \arabic{KSRLessonNumberCounter}: {#2}}
        \stepcounter{KSRLessonNumberCounter}
}
\newcommand{\KSRSubsection}[1]{
        \subsection*{#1}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\KSRLessonNumber}{
}

\begin{document}

\KSRSection{Sample}

This is the first lesson. The second lesson is \nameref{sec:blah}.

\KSRSection{Blah}
\label{sec:blah}

This is the second section

\KSRSection{Lorem Ipsum}

Dollars are Set in \nameref{sec:blah}.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE: wrong section numbers]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is an expansion issue. The title string is not expanded and contains:

```
Lesson \arabic {KSRLessonNumberCounter}: Blah
```

Package `hyperref` loads `nameref`, which uses package `gettitlestring` to get a clean title string (removing `\label`, `\index`, ...). There are two methods, the traditional way without expansion or the version with expansion. The former is the default. By switching to method `expand` the problem is solved:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}% loads gettitlestring
\GetTitleStringSetup{expand}
```

Answer (score 6):

A different solution than Heiko's that uses standard names. You simply enter `\subsection` for subsections, without the need of `*`; for the reference to a section, use `\lectref`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt, twoside]{exam}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{Lesson \csname the#1\endcsname: }
\makeatother

\newcommand{\lectref}[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{Lesson~\ref*{#1}: \nameref*{#1}}%
}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\section{Sample}

This is the first lesson. The second lesson is \lectref{sec:blah}.

\section{Blah}\label{sec:blah}

This is the second section

\subsection{A subsection}

Here it is

\section{Lorem Ipsum}

Dollars are Set in \lectref{sec:blah}.

\end{document}
```

I used `colorlinks` to show them in the picture.

[image]