# Make hyperref expand section titles when \label is executed?

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, expansion

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\ordinal}{First}
\section{\ordinal{} Section}
\label{sec:first}

\renewcommand*{\ordinal}{Second}
\section{\ordinal{} Section}
\label{sec:second}

I want this to say ``First Section'': \nameref{sec:first}

\end{document}
```

I end up with `\newlabel{sec:first}{{1}{1}{\ordinal {} Section}{section.1}{}}` in the `.aux` file, whereas I wanted `\ordinal{}` to be expanded immediately when the `\label` command is executed.  Is there any sane way to make hyperref expand the section title when writing out the `\newlabel` command?

Comment: Try [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/165183/14500)...

Comment: You can use `\expandafter\section\expandafter{\ordinal{} Section}` as well, but this might get tedious for more than a few occurences of `\ordinal`

Comment: @PaulGaborit That's it exactly, thank you!  All my searching did not find that.  I think my question is a duplicate of that existing one.  If more experience TeX.SE users disagree, I'd be happy to select an answer you post as the correct answer here.